# Controlling which user runs a app-script in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My question is exactly what the title suggests.

I have in my google sheet - that is collaboratively shared between 3 different people,
3 different functions attached to buttons. But all functions are currently in 1 app-script file.

The collaborators represent a worker, a reporting manager 1 and another manager 2.
So worker should only click his own button and run his script, and not the buttons that do duties for the managers.

I have set controls for the cell areas and ranges as per user roles-  that documentation is clearly available.

Managers also should not be able to click the worker button.
This should be a commonly occuring paradigm - how can one solve this?

Comment: Can you just have one of the things that each script does be to write to a cell (a timestamp maybe?) that only that person has access to edit? that way it'll fail if the "clicker" shouldn't be running the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using images as buttons and assigning a script to them, then you could try something like this:

```js
function button() {
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  if(user != "user@domain.com")
  {
    // This shows an alert explaining the user that they do not have access
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Error, you do not have access to his button");
    
    // You can just set a return if you don't want the script to do anything
    return
  }
  else
  {
    //Introduce your script here
  }
}
```

This would validate if the user that clicks that specific button is actually the one that should have permissions. Just be aware that any user with editor access to the file is able to edit the script as well.

You can add this validation to each button and just change the email address of the user that should have access to run the script.

#### References:

- [getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser)
- [Class Session](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session)
- [getEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user#getemail)

Comment: I can only think of one more direct method - to create an external un-bounded appscript, to which separate permissions can be set, and the same code above used in it. In that case, the appscript would not be changeable or even visible to the people inside the googlesheet.